# I am getting very strange results with Laravel 5, a custom database config, and MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-artisan

I am using Laravel 5 with a .env and also a config/database.php file that reads as follows:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'default' => 'mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'unix_socket' => getenv('UNIX_SOCKET'),
    'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => ''),
```

`php artisan migrate` fails when I run it, claiming that the Database is not configured. However, I suspect I am doing something wrong in my config file because when I run `php artisan -V` I get this?

```
>php artisan -V
'mysql' => array(
    'default' => 'mysql',
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'unix_socket' => getenv('UNIX_SOCKET'),
    'host' => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => ''
),Laravel Framework version Lumen (5.1.1) (Laravel Components 5.1.*)
```

php artisan appears to be just printing out my config file and is ignoring it?

Comment: are you returning an array from the config file and do you have a `<?php` tag opening it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel and Lumen config files need to be structured properly for them to work. Also `getenv()` is not the function you want, instead you need `env()`. The database config needs to be structured like this (just swap out your variables):

```
<?php

return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'      => env('DB_PORT', 3306),
            'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
            'timezone'  => env('DB_TIMEZONE','+00:00'),
            'strict'    => false,
        ]
    ]
];
```

[Here's a the full Lumen database config file for your reference.](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/blob/5.1/config/database.php)

Comment: Well, I copied your code here and while I don't get the repeat of the config file, I still get errors. One thing: I have the .env file in place, so why should I set variables with `env()` as opposed to get the ones I have already with `getenv()`? The error I am getting is `1103 Incorrect table name ` but I am definitely filling out my own correct settings.

Comment: `env()` gets the environment variable you specify in the first variable. If it doesn't exist the second argument is the default. Incorrect table name... that is a different question as the config is clearly working and you're connected to the database. Try checking table names in your models?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about `getenv()` versus `env()`; that makes sense. No models yet; just trying to run php artisan migrate:install. Weirdly, I solved the problem by switching to this sqlite implementation: http://bit.ly/1Ninhom

Comment: I looked over your reference to the full Lumen database config file and there is no mention of a 'unix_socket' option which is something I have had to use with Laravel and MAMP. All recommendations have suggested that I just switch to vagrant instead of MAMP, but is that option to enter the unix socket really just not available?

Comment: Try setting the Unix socket to the host instead of an IP address or localhost.